# Formatting a datetime string in the YYYYMMDD format

Tags: c#, strings, datetime, formatting

I'm working with some strange APIs that requires the dates to be sent in the YYYYMMDD format.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
string date = string.Concat(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
```

Is there a better practice?

Comment: Be careful when calling `DateTime.Now` several times like this. For example, if `DateTime.Now.Month` is called just before the midnight of 31 January and `DateTime.Now.Day` after the midnight, you will get the date like `20120101`. It's unlikely, but certainly possible.

Comment: This is already 'answered', but the main difference between their method and yours is how 1 digit months and dates will be handled. Yours would print 201911 for 1st Jan 2019, whereas the others will print 20190101

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes there is: [Date Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

```
var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to create an extension methods like:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string ToYMD(this DateTime theDate)
    {
        return theDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    }

    public static string ToYMD(this DateTime? theDate)
    {
        return theDate.HasValue ? theDate.Value.ToYMD() : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

You would use it like:

```
var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToYMD();
```

The extension implemented also works for Nullable DateTime values.

If you are doing a lot of work with these 'yyyyMMdd' formatted DateTime values, the extension method has the benefit of less typing.